istio rate limit - envoy rate limit config
I am trying to setup 2 rate limits (minute and hour) for one header value. Below is envoy filter file and rate limit config file:
envoy-filter:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: filter-ratelimit-actions
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: VIRTUAL_HOST
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: ""
            route:
              action: ANY
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        # Applies the rate limit rules.
        value:
          rate_limits:
            - actions:
              - request_headers:
                  header_name: host
                  descriptor_key: HOST
              - request_headers:
                  header_name: cf-connecting-ip
                  descriptor_key: CF_CONNECTING_IP
              - request_headers:
                  header_name: my-graphql-path
                  descriptor_key: GRAPHQL_PATH
              - generic_key:
                  descriptor_value: "MINUTE_LIMIT"
            - actions:
              - request_headers:
                  header_name: host
                  descriptor_key: HOST
              - request_headers:
                  header_name: cf-connecting-ip
                  descriptor_key: CF_CONNECTING_IP
              - request_headers:
                  header_name: my-graphql-path
                  descriptor_key: GRAPHQL_PATH
              - generic_key:
                  descriptor_value: "HOUR_LIMIT"

ratelimit-config:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ratelimit-config
data:
  config.yaml: |
    domain: all-ratelimit
    descriptors:
      - key: HOST
        value: "example.com"
        descriptors:
          # White list IP:
          - key: CF_CONNECTING_IP
            value: xx.xx.xx.xx
            rate_limit:
              unlimited: true
          - key: CF_CONNECTING_IP
            rate_limit:
              unit: hour
              requests_per_unit: 5000
            descriptors:
              - key: GRAPHQL_PATH
                value: "signInEmail"
                descriptors:
                  - key: MINUTE_LIMIT
                    rate_limit:
                      unit: minute
                      requests_per_unit: 3
                  - key: HOUR_LIMIT
                    rate_limit:
                      unit: hour
                      requests_per_unit: 100

But, minute and hour keys are not getting logged on redis database.
